# how to retrieve child array from firebase database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a two nodes of "users" and "posts" in my firebase database,

1. post node contains the post data and "attachedUsers" child - containing an array of user ids of other users (at least 4 )
2. The users node contains the user data such as name and date of creation.

I am trying to retrieve the posts from the database, in doing so , i need to retrieve the "attachedUsers" profile images for which i have to loop around in  each "users" node to get the image url. any way i could achieve that?

Also, i just need to **display** the first four profile images of the "attachedUsers" child only, For now i have 4 image views separately for the images, But is that legible? shall i use collection view instead to display those (but for that i need to put that collection view in the table view cell of the post.)

my code for retrieving the post :

```
func fetchingPost() {
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    print("start")
    ref.child("posts").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in

        let group = DispatchGroup()
        for snap in snapshot.children {
            self.arrayOfUid.removeAll()
            group.enter()
            let postSnap = snap as! DataSnapshot
            let postKey = postSnap.key
            let postDict = postSnap.value as! [String:AnyObject]
            let aPost = PostClass()
            aPost.key = postKey

            aPost.content = postDict["description"] as! String
            aPost.topic = postDict["topic"] as! String

            let attachedUsers = postDict["attachedUsers"] as! [String]
            let userReference = ref.child("users")
            userReference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snap) in
                let userDict_ = snap.value as! [String : AnyObject]
                print("\(attachedUsers) theeeeee")

                for (_,value) in userDict_ {
                    var array = [String]()
                    print("\(attachedUsers) weeeeeee")
                    for each in attachedUsers {
                        if each == value["uid"] as? String {
                            let UidImages = value["urlToImage"] as! String
                            array.append(UidImages)
                            aPost.attachedUserUrls = array
                            array.removeAll()
                            print( "\(aPost.attachedUserUrls) this is ")

                        }
                    }


                }
            }


            let uid = postDict["userID"] as! String
            let userRef = ref.child("users").child(uid)
            userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
                let userDict = snapshot.value as! [String:AnyObject]
                let userImage = userDict["urlToImage"] as! String
                aPost.imageUrl = userImage
                self.postArray.append(aPost)
                print(self.postArray.count)
                group.leave()

            }

        }


        group.notify(queue: .main) {
            print("All callbacks are completed")
            self.TableViewControllerHome.reloadData()
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: To load the posts and the profile pics for the attached users, you'll need a nested listener. Your code is already doing that, so what is the problem with this code? When you run it (maybe in a debugger), which line doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: @frank van puffelen  the "attachedusers" profiles are not loading well , I mean all the profile images of the array  urls of "attachedusers" are not being retrieved.